# Converting executable to code

Tags: c, debugging, unix, operating-system

I know this question may be weird. But I just want to know whether it is possible for any executable (.exe or a.out) to be converted back to source code ? Is there any tool ? If no then please ignore the question .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be [Boomerang](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boomerang/) can be of some help.

Comment: +1 Thanks for that! [*Edit:* Oh, the project looks fairly dead...]

Comment: It's dead, but I just gave because at least it's *something* that OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "the source code". The program could have been assembled in any number of ways. (E.g. it could have been written in Pascal, COBOL, or even directly in machine code.) The best thing you can do is to "disassemble" the program, i.e. turn the machine code in readable assembler mnemonics. If you have a strong understanding of how compilers are implemented, then you may well be able to recognize the usual patterns and infer some sort of equivalent C code.

There are tools that use heuristics based on such knowledge and automate the process. I don't know any open-source ones, but I think the [IDA Disassembler](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/overview.shtml) goes some way towards that goal.

Answer (score 1):

Hh, if you mean *convert back to assembler source code*, yes there's very easy way to do this (on linux maxhines): `objdump --disassemble <binaryname>`, you sure can use some windows [disassembler](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=windows%20disassemble#hl=en&sa=X&ei=Hz0nT6LuDsvO-QaOtqC9CA&ved=0CCUQBSgA&q=windows%20disassembler&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=b760c267e252527&biw=1280&bih=962).

You you mean *original C source code*, there are two options. When you're trying to reverse application which was compiled using debugging symbols (such as `gcc -g ...`), than you should be able to get source codes via debugger (in gdb it would be command like this: `disassemble /m`).

And if you're not using them... Than you should google for [reverse engineering](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=-g%20get%20source%20code#pq=c%20gdb%20get%20source&hl=en&sugexp=pfwl&tok=5ocg-gz7Wi-xrJKG7PARAQ&cp=10&gs_id=32&xhr=t&q=reverse%20engineering&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=reverse%20en&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=b760c267e252527&biw=1280&bih=962) :)